# Mapping external errors to domain errors in golang

Tags: go, error-handling, abstraction

I have a service type called `ComputeService` which implements certain domain logic. The service itself depends on implementation of an interface called `Computer` which has a method `Computer.Compute(args...) (value, error)`.  As shown, `Compute` itself might return certain errors.

`ComputeService` needs to send appropriate errors from a set of domain-errors with proper domain-error code so that translations can be done and also clients can handle errors appropriately.

My question is, should the `Computer` implementations be wrapping their failure in domain-errors or should `ComputeService` do this. If `ComputeService` is the one doing it, then it will have to know about different errors returned by different implementations of `Computer` interface which in my opinion breaks the abstraction. Both ways are demonstrated below:

```
package arithmetic
type Computer struct {
}
func (ac Computer) Compute(args ....) (value, error) {
     // errors is a domain-errors package defined in compute service project
     return errors.NewDivideByZero()
}
```

OR

```
package compute
type Service struct {
}
func (svc Service) Process(args...) error {
    computer := findComputerImplementation(args...)
    val, err := computer.Compute(args...)
    if err != nil {
       if err == arith.ErrDivideByZero {
          // converting an arithmetic computer implementation 
          // specific error to domain error
          return errors.NewDivideByZero()
       } else if err == algebra.ErrInvalidCoEfficient {
          // converting an algebraic computer implementation 
          // specific error to domain error
          return errors.NewBadInput()
       }
       // some new implementation was used and we have no idea
       // what errors it could be returning. so we have to send
       // a internal server error equivalent here
       return errors.NewInternalError()
    }

}
```

Comment: Or you could combine: return a single error type that wraps a particular `Computer`-specific error.

Comment: Like `errors.NewComputerFailure(err)` ?

Comment: Yep ...............

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not possible since at the very least, my http handlers need to differentiate between client errors and internal errors.. For example, if a `Computer` implementation depends on a db/external service and that fails, it's a internal error.. But if client sends a compute request which requires dividing by zero, it's a client error. So mapping all `Compute` errors into one `ComputeFailure` wouldn't work.

Comment: I am not asking it to be automatically. My question was **where** should the domain error be generated. Should the `Compute` implementation return constant errors defined in `arith`, `algebra` etc. packages, and `ComputeService` maps it to its own error types or `Compute` implementation itself return appropriate domain errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementors of `Computer` should respond with the domain errors, since they're the closest ones to the action and best able to determine what an error is. Like you said, having that logic *in* `ComputeService` breaks the abstraction. If you need mapping code from specific `Computer` errors to domain errors, create wrapper structs that separate the main logic from that error wrapping code.

To keep internal error context, just embed the original error in the domain error and make `IsSpecificDomainError` helpers.

```
type MyDomainError struct {
    Err error
}

func NewMyDomainErr(err error) error {
    return &MyDomainError{err}
}

func IsMyDomainError(e error) bool {
    _, ok := err.(*MyDomainError)
    return ok
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In addition to the original question, in your opinion does this apply to `Repository` objects as well ? For example, should the `UserRepository.FindUserByID(uid)` return `ErrNoRecordFound` (where `var ErrNoRecordFound = erros.New("no record")` or should it directly return `MyDomainError{"no such user", uid} ` ?

Comment: If you've standardized on the ErrNoRecordFound for _all_ implementors, then I would say that satisfies the interface and interpretation in the service is ok. I guess my answer would more simply be: if the wrapping service needs to understand it, then it needs to be of a known type, and that should be considered part of "implementing" the interface. Whether that is ErrNoRecordFound or a specific domain error isn't really material.

Answer (score 1):

> To keep internal error context, just embed the original error in the domain error

This can use Wrapping errors, which are on their way for Go 1.13 (Q4 2019), from [issue 29934](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29934), as [detailed here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29934#issuecomment-489682919).

**err.Is()**:

As Russ Cox [mentions](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29934#issuecomment-490546708):

> I think we all agree that `strings.Contains(err.Error(), "not found")` is fragile code.
>
> I hope we also agree that we'd prefer to see code like `errors.Is(err, os.ErrNotExist)`.
>
> But the point is that in many cases, it is essential to future evolution of a package to keep callers from depending on a particular error result satisfying `errors.Is(err, os.ErrNotExist)`, even if that is the underlying cause in *today*'s result.
>   It's like looking at an unexported field or comparing error text - it's a detail that might change.
>
> And while `strings.Contains` looks and is fragile, `errors.Is` does not look nor should be considered fragile.
>   If we are to avoid it being fragile, then we need to provide a way for packages to report detail without letting clients test for it. That way is errors that can't be unwrapped.

**err.As()**:

```
var pe *os.PathError
if errors.As(err, &pe) {
     use(pe)
}
```

[**%w**](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29934#issuecomment-458229227):

```
func inner() error { return errors.New("inner error") }
func outer() error { return fmt.Errorf("outer error: %w", inner()) }

fmt.Fprintf("%+v", outer())
// outer error:
//     /path/to/file.go:123
//   - inner error:
//     /path/to/file.go:122
```

The [current status for Go 1.13](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29934#issuecomment-490456945):

> Just stating what I see as the compromise solution offered by the team:
>
> - `fmt.Errorf` is currently being used extensively to wrap errors and return a new (opaque) error (as in you cannot access the underlying error).
>     '`%w`' can now be used to explicitly opt-in to return an error that can be unwrapped.
> - errors is designed as a base package with no dependencies so that every package can depend on it.
> - the team agrees to punt on the areas that there is broad disagreement, and want to release just enough (errors.Is, errors.As, extension to way most folks wrap errors) so folks can achieve things.
> - Generics is not here yet, and we do not know when it will come: the heated discussion on that will make this one on "error 2 values" look like child's play.
>     `errors.Is` and `errors.As` are clean and concise enough to be comfortable for a long time.
>
> Most of the contentious things have been punted to go 1.14.
>
> - `Wrapf` cannot live in errors as it is a base package.
> - `Wrapf` means team MUST decide on what happens when a `nil` error is passed: Punt on it.
> - Wrap may conflict with ideas being considered for localization, internationalization, etc.
> - `ErrorFormatter` and `ErrorPrinter` have not yet gotten much deeper usage and have warts. Punt.